# Cytoscape.js layout edge length

Tags: cytoscape.js

Hi I'm trying to build a web-crawler visualization tool for a school project.  I decided to use Cytoscape.js and it's been really nice to use.  The problem i'm having is the edge lengths for some of the layouts (circle, breadth first, concentric) seem too large and the graph looks odd.

When I first start the application, I manually make and load a graph(it's a tree) with 100 nodes and that looks good in Circle layout:
[image]

However after I perform a web-crawl the new graph( this one has 44 nodes) doesn't fit in the view for circle:
[image]

Is there a way to get this to work so that the edges are not so long and the nodes look larger?

Edit:

Here's the code I use to change the layout:

```
changeLayout = function(layoutName, title,  root){
                var numOfNodes = cy.filter('node').length;
                //extent changes when I repeatedly change the layout to circle, (don't understand this behavior)
                var extent = cy.extent();
                var rect = document.getElementById("cy-container").getBoundingClientRect();

                var x1 = rect.left;
                var x2 = rect.right;
                var y1 = rect.top;
                var y2 = rect.bottom;

                var height = (y2 - y1);
                var width = (x2 - x1);

                var fact = (height < width) ? (height/numOfNodes) : (width/numOfNodes);
                fact *= 5;
                var myRadius = height < width ? (height-fact) : (width-fact);

                switch(layoutName){
                        case 'circle':
                                myLayout = cy.makeLayout(
                                {       name: layoutName,
                                        radius: myRadius,
                                        boundingBox: {x1: x1, x2: x2, y1: y1, y2: y2},
                                        fit: true,
                                        avoidOverlap: false
                                });
                                break;
                        case 'concentric':
                                myLayout = cy.makeLayout(
                                {       name: layoutName,
                                        height: height,
                                        width: width,
                                        fit: false,
                                        avoidOverlap: true
                                });
                                break;
                        case 'breadthfirst':
                                myLayout = cy.makeLayout(
                                {       name: layoutName,
                                        boundingBox: {x1: x1, x2: x2, y1: y1, y2: y2},
                                        fit: true,
                                        roots: root,
                                        avoidOverlap: false
                                });
                                break;
                        default :
                                myLayout = cy.makeLayout(
                                {
                                        name: layoutName
                                });
                }

                myLayout.run();
                $('#graphTitle').text(title + " Layout");
        };
```

Comment: This could be a variety of things. Likely it's linked to the layout function. Can you post all of your cytoscape code so we can better understand the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The length of an edge is a function of the positions of the nodes.  The layout sets the positions, so you have to set the layout options to make the nodes closer together.

For force-directed (physics simulation) layouts, you adjust the forces.  In other layouts, you can adjust spacing values or enforce a bounding box to affect how spread out the nodes are.

Comment: Thanks I noticed some things I don't understand, 
I tried to set the bounding box using the extent, but when I repeatedly set the Circular or Concentric layouts I notice that the cy.extent() keeps changing and causes the nodes to looks smaller and smaller.  So I used getBoundingClientRect() on the container holding the graph.  That seems to work for circle and breadthfirst but concentric looks off.  For concentric if I turn avoid overlap off then the nodes seem to really want to stack on top of each other.

Comment: If you don't use automatic overlap avoidance, then you have to set the bounding box large enough such that the nodes wouldn't overlap.  We have planned some features to make this usecase easier in future versions, but they're a bit farther down the priority list.  [This one](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/1266) would be enough for your usecase.  If you'd like to make a PR for it, it would be much appreciated and the feature would be in the next feature release.

Comment: Sure i'd be happy to make a pr, how do I make the request?